# Почему возникает ошибка типа "cannot read property style of null"?

Tags: javascript

Выдаёт ошибку типа "cannot read property style of null".
Что пытаюсь сделать: после движения мышкой к курсору должно прилипнуть изображение (сначала прописал его ссылкой, затем решил попробовать подгрузить со своего компа) и далее двигаться за курсором по экрану.
Но что-то пошло не так. 
Консоль показывает, что события происходят, счётчик крутится, но в 4-й строчке обнаруживается ошибка.

```js
document.onmousemove = function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', '<img src="evernote.png" id="cat"');
  var cat = document.getElementById('cat');
  cat.style.position = 'fixed';

  document.onmousemove = function(event) {
    cat.style.left = event.clientX + 20 + 'px';
    cat.style.top = event.clientY + 20 + 'px';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.onmousemove = function() {
  // во-первых не   document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
  // а document.body без индекса
  // и во-вторых в этой стороке <img src="evernote.png" id="cat"/> пропустил закрывающую скобку 
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', '<img src="evernote.png" id="cat"/>');
  var cat = document.getElementById('cat');
  cat.style.position = 'fixed';

  document.onmousemove = function(event) {
    cat.style.left = event.clientX + 20 + 'px';
    cat.style.top = event.clientY + 20 + 'px';
  }
}
```

---

```js
/*обрати внимание что если у BODY не прописан heigth, то он по умолчанию равен нулю и ты мышку двигаешь не в body, а в html*/

// данным способом  ( document.onmousemove ) ты двигаешь мышкой по html
//и этот пример не будет работать

//  смотри пример три

 document.body.onmousemove = function() {

      document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', '<img src="evernote.png" id="cat"/>');
      var cat = document.getElementById('cat');
      cat.style.position = 'fixed';

       document.body.onmousemove = function(event) {
        cat.style.left = event.clientX + 20 + 'px';
        cat.style.top = event.clientY + 20 + 'px';
      }
    }
```

```css
html{
background:red;
}

body{
background:green;
}
```

---

Вариант ТРИ

```js
// В данном варианте, когда у body прописан height ты уже двигаешь мышкой в body


document.body.onmousemove = function() {

  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', '<img src="evernote.png" id="cat"/>');
  var cat = document.getElementById('cat');
  cat.style.position = 'fixed';

  document.body.onmousemove = function(event) {
    cat.style.left = event.clientX + 20 + 'px';
    cat.style.top = event.clientY + 20 + 'px';
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}

body {
  background: green;
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73353/discussion-on-answer-by-air-----cannot-read-property-s).